# Is it possible to download azure pipeline artifact to local folder within pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have an Azure pipeline in which I create an artifact (a folder around 400 MB)

```
...

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'PublishArtifact'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

Is it possible to download it to my local folder (let's say: C:\test) with a command within this same pipeline?
(I can download it manually if I go to Pipelines -> 'The latest build' -> Under Related, I have published artifact, but I want to do this automatically within pipeline with some command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it during pipeline execution you should install self hosted agent on your machine. Here you have links:

- [Self-hosted Linux agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops)
- [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops)

Then you need to condogure pipeline to use this agent.

Another option would be FTP upload. In this way you need to configure you machine as FTP server and use for instance [this task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops). In this approach you can still use MS Hosted agent.

Comment: Thank you, I configured my machine as FTP server and used FTP upload task in Azure Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be possible if you **add your computer as a deployment group** (See [Provision deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003203)). Then your build could trigger a classic Release pipeline where you can copy the artifact to a folder within you local machine

Answer (score 0):

You can use Copy file task as explained in this doc

[Copy file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)